# KEEP_ALIVE still sending packets to server after network cable or server disconnected

Tags: c++, windows, keep-alive, winsock2

I have simple client server application, which I have downloaded from MSDN. I have used WSAIoCtl function to send keep-alive packets to the server(), which will eventually throw WSACONNRESET if the server does not respond upon maximum retries done by a client application. I can see keep alive packets (in Wireshark tool) while both are connected. Now if I unplugged the cable I can still see those keep alive packets being sent to the server and received at the client side. The process goes on indefinite time. I am unable to understand how this could happen, as my server is no longer attached to network still connection stays in ESTABLISHED state.
I am wondering how this could be possible. If I close my server while being connected to the client, I can see keep alive packets running on WireShark. There is no way I can detect a broken connection.

I receive FIN/ACK from server while I closing server application, still keep alive continues to run.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Have you considered a ghost?  As in, you think you are talking to a server over the network, but are actually talking to a ghost of the server locally on your machine?  Either that, or you are using the APIs wrong.  Or your computer is talking over wifi to a different server than the one you expect?

Comment: When I run C-S application within the network (intranet), I can see keep alive packets in Wireshark both in client and server machine. But when the client is connected to the server over the internet, but within same organisation domain, I could not see any keep-alive packets at the server side. Is there any concept of loopbacks, if so how to detect them on demand.